# How get data by month using DBFlow?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm facing some problems trying get a list of months and a list of data by month from my database in my app. Now I'm using strftime() function from SQLite but apparently the strftime() doesn't work.
For building and managing the database I'm using DBFlow ORM and the query of the first list looks like that.

```
List<ExpenseAndIncome> expenseAndIncomes = new Select("strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date").from(ExpenseAndIncome.class).queryList();

SELECT `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)` FROM `expense_and_income`
```

In this case it shows up an exception

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)` FROM `expense_and_income`
```

The other problem occurs when I'm trying to get a list of data by month. In this case the query looks like that.

```
List<ExpenseAndIncome> expenseAndIncomes = new Select().from(ExpenseAndIncome.class).where("strftime('%m', date) = ?", calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)).groupBy("date").queryList();

SELECT * FROM `expense_and_income` WHERE strftime('%m', date) = 7 GROUP BY date
```

But the result always is a empty array.

Can someone helpe me?

Comment: apparently it works: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html DBFlow is not using it correctly, `\`` is not SQLite

Comment: @njzk2 `\`` is supported by SQLite for compatibility with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve one of the problems, getting a list of data by months.

When Android executes the following line in SQLite

```
List<ExpenseAndIncome> expenseAndIncomes = new Select().from(ExpenseAndIncome.class).where("strftime('%m', date) = ?", calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)).groupBy("date").queryList();
```

Query representation

```
SELECT * FROM `expense_and_income` WHERE strftime('%m', date) = 7 GROUP BY date
```

They compare something like that

```
SELECT * FROM `expense_and_income` WHERE '08' = 7 GROUP BY date
```

And this occurs because my date table save the dates as string and calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) returns an int as month representation and that int starts from 0. So, august is represented by the int 7 not 8 nor string '08'. SQLite query compares '08' with int 7 and because of this that array always are returned empty.

To solve this problem I created a method that returns a correct string representation to use in query comparison. The final code looks something like this:

```
List<ExpenseAndIncome> expenseAndIncomes = new Select().from(ExpenseAndIncome.class).where("strftime('%m', date) = ?", getMonthAsString(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH))).groupBy("date").queryList();

private String getMonthAsString(int month) {
    if (month > 0 && month < Constants.OCTOBER)
        return Constants.ZERO + (Integer.toString(month) + 1);
    return Integer.toString((month + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strftime` is just a function that formats a Date variable as a string. For example, `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)` might return `'2015-08-17'`.

Your query, then, is being evaluated as:

```
SELECT 2015-08-17 FROM expense_and_income
```

That's not really what you want. I imagine you want something more like:

```
SELECT UNIQUE month FROM expense_and_income
```

Assuming you have a field called month, that is.

Your second query is being evaluated as

```
SELECT * FROM expense_and_income WHERE 08 = 7 GROUP BY date
```

Obviously, 8 != 7, so while this is a valid query, it never returns anything. You probably want something more like

```
SELECT * FROM expense_and_income WHERE month = 08
```